# Avoiding duplicate inserts using NOT EXISTS in SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, vba, sql-server-2008

I have this code below that I'm currently building to restrict the duplication of insertion of data in my database. Unfortunately, it catches some error. I searched and tried several combinations but somehow, I can't get it right.

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTableMenu "
sSQL &= "(MenuID, MenuPosition) "
sSQL &= "VALUES ('" & sValue & "', " & i + 1 & ") "
sSQL &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblTableSettings WHERE MenuID = '" & 
sValue & "')"
```

The above code is written like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblTableMenu (MenuID, MenuPosition) 
VALUES ('SAMPLE', 1)  
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblTableSettings WHERE MenuID = 'SAMPLE')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` command in T-SQL does **NOT** allow a `WHERE` clause. You need to check **first** and only fire the `INSERT` if you really want to do the insert.

You need to do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblTableSettings WHERE MenuID = 'SAMPLE')
   INSERT INTO tblTableMenu (MenuID, MenuPosition) 
   VALUES ('SAMPLE', 1)
```

It seems odd, though, that your `NOT EXISTS()` check the `tblTableSettings`, while the `INSERT` actually goes against the `tblTableMenu` table..... is that **on purpose**, or just an oversight??

Comment: I don't know if im doing this right but im checking the tblTableSettings if there is an existing datas and if not, i will put it in my tblTableMenu.

Comment: Also, i tried your suggestion, but it's still firing it up on my tblTableMenu which duplicates the returned values.

Comment: Well, if you want to be sure not to insert duplicates into `tblTableMenu`, then you really must check `tblTableMenu` with the `IF EXISTS()` - anything else will not work reliably.

Comment: Yes, i was about to thank you. I just found the glitch on my code and it's as exactly as you said. Thank you so much! Highly appreciated! God bless!